# Selecting and Closing djTabPane in djTabContainer

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs, xpages-extlib

I wonder, if someone has THE CLUE for me on one of my devel problem (sure you do ;-) ).

I try to use a "Dojo Tab Container" with dynamic Dojo Tab Panes.

```
<xp:div id="tabs">
    <xe:djTabContainer id="djTabContainer1" tabPosition="top"
        style="height:250px;width:500px" defaultTabContent="defTab">
        <xp:this.facets>
            <xe:djTabPane xp:key="defTab" id="myTab" partialEvents="true" closable="true">
                <xp:panel>
                    <xp:label value="#{javascript:getComponent('myTab').getTitle()}"></xp:label>
                </xp:panel>
            </xe:djTabPane>
        </xp:this.facets>
    </xe:djTabContainer>
</xp:div>
```

Then there's a SSJS (button) event to add tabs (actually the action is more complex to calculate title etc., but this should explain):

```
var cont:com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.dojo.layout.UIDojoTabContainer = getComponent('djTabContainer1');
cont.createTab({id:'tab1', tabUniqueKey:'tab1', tabTitle:'tab1'});
cont.createTab({id:'tab2', tabUniqueKey:'tab2', tabTitle:'tab2'});
cont.createTab({id:'tab3', tabUniqueKey:'tab3', tabTitle:'tab3'});
```

Now I want to programmatically switch (open) to another tab, or close a tab. It's quite difficult to find useful examples here.

I found out, that I can programmatically switch to another tab via **cont.setSelectedTab('*2*')** instead of **cont.setSelectedTab('*tab2*')** - as I would expect. For some reason the **tabUniqueKey** parameter is fully ignored, while the **tabTitle** parameter isn't. Even worse: it looks like all createTab()-parameters are ignored, except of tabTitle.

Is there an elegant way to get the tab pane component? **getComponent('tab2')** doesn't work. Neither "**id:'tab2'**" nor "**tabUniqueKey:'tab2'**" are taken in account. I can get *a* tab using **getComponent('myTab')**, but that's fully useless, if all tabs have the same id.

So, neither does

```
var cont:com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.dojo.layout.UIDojoTabContainer = getComponent('djTabContainer1'); 
var tabSel:com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.dojo.layout.UIDojoTabPane = comp.selectTab('tab2');
```

nor

```
var tabSel:com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.dojo.layout.UIDojoTabPane = comp.setSelectedTab('tab2');
```

At least what I'm looking for is something similar to:

```
cont.closeTab('tab3'); // to close tab3
```

Answer (score 1):

`createTab()` returns a UIDojoTabPane pane object and you can use it to *select* the created tab afterwards:

```
var cont:com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.dojo.layout.UIDojoTabContainer = getComponent('djTabContainer1');
var paneTab1:com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.dojo.layout.UIDojoTabPane = cont.createTab({id:'tab1', tabUniqueKey:'tab1', tabTitle:'tab1'});
...
cont.setSelectedTab(paneTab1.getTabUniqueKey());
```

You can use this pane object to *close* the tab too:

```
paneTab1.closeTab()
```

Comment: Knut, thank you for your answer !! Your solution works great !

Comment: Sorry, Knut, I lost track of this. :(  Yes, that helped a lot. Thanks for your great reply.

Comment: Thomas, great. Please consider to accept the answer like described here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/223607. Thanks